# Efficient way to timeout waiting for a state change (variable change)?

Tags: python, performance, timeout

I'm sure this is somewhat common, so I am curious what are the accepted/efficient ways of doing this in Python.

Put simply, I am just busy-waiting for a variable to be updated. At the same time I need a timeout scheme, but I feel there must be a better way of doing this.

Currently I do something like this:

```
wait_start = time.time()
while state != NEW_STATE:
    if time.time() - wait_start > timeout:
        print "Timed out!"
        # Do something

# Continuing on...
```

I obviously just can't sleep, because I need to know when the state has changed.

So what is an efficient method of implementing a timeout for a state (variable) change?

Comment: ouch.  when state != NEW_STATE, you will eat cpu cycles checking it

Comment: exactly, I thought about signals, but I just figured that there is an accepted best-practice for this sort of thing

Answer (score 1):

[Condition variables](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#condition-objects) and [events](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#event-objects) are often used for this type of thing. Both require cooperation from the side that's changing the variable.